# Can I remove previous versions of iphone support in DeviceSupport folder in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, ios, sdk, xcode4, ios4

In my quest to find out why Xcode is so big, i found out that a lot of the space is taken up by the subfolders to the Developer>Platforms>iPhoneOS.platform>DeviceSupport folder..

Since I am (apparently) only allowed to develop for the last of them in Xcode, can I safely remove the rest (in this case 3.0 to 4.2.1)?

Same question regarding the subfolders of Developer>Platforms>iPhoneSimulator.platform>Developer>SDKs..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can remove SKDs prior to 4.0 in `Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` it's just old stuff.

For the subfolders in `Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer` it's all the devices version that you will find in iOS Simulator in the menu Hardware>Device>Version. It can be sometimes usefull to keep them to test retrocompatibility (But remember that a test on a real device is still better). But if you want you can also remove these SKDs.

Comment: Thanks! I actually never realized that you could test backwards compatibility that way.. Guess I assumed that since I could only test on devices with the newest OS, the same was true for the sim..

Comment: BTW.. Just find out you can test on old devices by setting Deployment Target to any previous SDK, so I guess thats why they keep the old DeploymenTargets around...