# Xcode 12.5 taking up 100s of GBs in CoreSimulator Folder

Tags: ios, xcode, disk

My computer recently keeps running out of space whenever I'm using Xcode with the simulator. I kept thinking it was the swap space so I eventually bit the bullet and cleared 100GB on my computer, only to have it entirely filled up again.

Some research found that the file `/Users/itai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{some random ID}/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/{some random ID}/{MySwiftAppName}.app` weighed 100GB!!

Clicking show package contents revealed a folder inside called "System" that had literally the entire iOS system in there (Podcasts app, mail app, etc. etc.) and running `ls -la` in terminal did not reveal it to be a link to another folder

Any ideas why this happened and how to keep it from happening again? And whether this system folder really is okay to delete it or if I am slowly going to find out that I need to re-install Xcode with new simulators?

Comment: I like a free utility you will find on the Mac App Store called Dev Cleaner

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431

Comment: Also see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419301/macos-xcode-coresimulator-folder-very-big-is-it-ok-to-delete-content?rq=1