# Xcode 12, iPadOS14.0.1 App won't start on device from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app and when I choose to run it on the device (an iPad pro) from Xcode, it just sits and the LaunchScreen.storyboard for 30-45 seconds.  Eventually and message pops up in the console that says:
`Metal API Validation Enabled` and it works normally.  Other people are having this issue.  Any thoughts from the world of smart people:

It's documented here too: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661008

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there are a lot of people with this issue.  By following the suggestions in these articles I got it down from 80 seconds to about 8-10.  While not good, it's way better.

Cheers.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651012
[Slow app launch time after updating to iOS 14 and Xcode 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929122/slow-app-launch-time-after-updating-to-ios-14-and-xcode-12)
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123068?answerId=420683022#420683022
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651012