# Running app on iOS 14.0.1 with Xcode 12.0.1 - white screen for long time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have updated my iPhone from 13.5 to 14.0.1 and run the application via Xcode. Building and loading the app from Xcode to iPhone takes 2-3 mins. It is used to be very very fast.

Xcode version is 12.0.1, iOS version is 14.0.1

How could I able to fix this issue?

Comment: similar question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929122/slow-app-launch-time-after-updating-to-ios-14-and-xcode-12

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I would like to share my solution as follows. It seems the issue has been fixed.

1. Unpair your phone from XCode
   Launch XCode with your phone not plugged in

   - plug your phone in
     under devices in XCode, unpair your phone
2. Stop XCode
3. Run the following commands

   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport

   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ Device\ Logs

   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
4. Start XCode
5. Plug phone in and build and install the app again via Xcode