# Building app on real device takes a few hours VS simulator build takes seconds/minutes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

Trying to build and run on device is now taking a few hours.

Device is running iOS 14.1

It seems like it is frozen on a task and then all of a sudden it starts running on the device after a few hours.

If I then stop and try to build and run again without any changes it takes hours again!

To run on simulator takes minutes if not seconds.

Xcode is running version 12.1.

It will run on the simulator and when I stop the build and then build and run again it loads immediately.

I've been searching many answers here on Stack but can't find anything that works.

Ive tried changing many things in the targets build settings but nothing is working!

Open to all suggestions, thanks✌️

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try deleting the Xcode cache files. You can do this by clicking on the apple logo -> about this Mac -> Storage -> manage -> Developer. There you’ll find the option to delete the cache. It’s worth a shot.

Comment: I don't have that 'Developer' option for some reason. There's an app called DevCleaner for Xcode, I just cleaned many GB of cached files but it makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, are you plugged into your phone or are you using it wirelessly? Maybe that could make a difference?

Comment: I've tried both, and both options work for building other apps, it's just this app that is not building. The only thing I haven't tried is deleting the app off my device but I use it so often that I can't afford to not be able to use it on my device

Comment: Have you tried this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929122/slow-app-launch-time-after-updating-to-ios-14-and-xcode-12